# How can I prevent my Modal content to scale when soft input is displayed in react native with react native navigation?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I use react native navigation to set up the navigation in my android app, I use startTabBasedApp() and I have a few modals that contain some text input, and when I tap TextInput and the android keyboard opens it resizes the content inside the Modal, what I really need it's to push the whole modal up and focus on the TextInput.

```
public class MyApplication extends NavigationApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This function works perfectly with the normal screens but it doesn't work for the Modals.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I am still looking for the solution too. Did you find it?